# Why does reference weakening from &mut occur in some trait method calls?

Tags: reference, rust, coercion

One of the few implicit conversions available in Rust is [pointer weakening](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html), which can turn a `&mut T` into a `&T`:

```
fn just_foo<T>(_: &T) {}

just_foo(&mut vec![1, 2, 3]);
```

However, this doesn't happen when matching traits. For instance, although the + operator with references as right-hand sided values is implemented for numeric types, they won't accept mutable references to the same type:

```
5 + &mut 5;
(&5) + &mut 5;
```

The error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `{integer}: std::ops::Add<&mut {integer}>` is not satisfied
--> src/main.rs:38:7
   |
38 | 5 + &mut 5;
   | ^ no implementation for `{integer} + &mut {integer}`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add<&mut {integer}>` is not implemented for `{integer}`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&{integer}: std::ops::Add<&mut {integer}>` is not satisfied
--> src/main.rs:43:10
   |
43 | (&5) + &mut 5;
   | ^ no implementation for `&{integer} + &mut {integer}`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add<&mut {integer}>` is not implemented for `&{integer}`
```

For another, more intriguing example, I added an assortment of implementations of `Add` for a unit type `Foo`:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Foo;

impl Add<Foo> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    fn add(self, _: Foo) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}

impl<'a> Add<&'a Foo> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    fn add(self, _: &'a Foo) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'a Foo> for &'b Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    fn add(self, _: &'a Foo) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}
```

Only to find that I can perform `&Foo + &mut Foo`, but not `Foo + &mut Foo`:

```
&Foo + &mut Foo; // ok
Foo + &mut Foo; // not ok
```

[Full Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=48be8fdf224f9a1bfb1abc5b18eaa400&version=stable)

The second case is in line with the previous example above, but the first one isn't. It seems that the RHS `&mut Foo` was coerced to `&Foo` to match the implementation of `&Foo + &Foo`. It doesn't look either that other coercions are taking place, because the receiving type for `&Foo as Add<&Foo>` is already `&Foo`. I could also throw the syntactic sugar away and obtain the same outcome:

```
(&Foo).add(&mut Foo); // ok
Foo.add(&mut Foo); // not ok
```

Given that coercions, according to the Nomicon, are not supposed to happen when doing trait matching, why does this `&Foo + &mut Foo` work when `&i32 + &mut i32` doesn't? Is it because there is a single implementation of `Add` for `&Foo`? If so, why does it make the compiler behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because there is a single implementation of `Add` for `&Foo`?

Let's see what happens when we add this implementation:

```
impl<'b> Add<Foo> for &'b Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    fn add(self, _: Foo) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}
```

Now `&Foo + &mut Foo` and `&Foo + &mut &mut Foo` fail to compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Foo: std::ops::Add<&mut Foo>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:39:10
   |
39 |     &Foo + &mut Foo;
   |          ^ no implementation for `&Foo + &mut Foo`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add<&mut Foo>` is not implemented for `&Foo`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Foo: std::ops::Add<&mut &mut Foo>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:40:10
   |
40 |     &Foo + &mut &mut Foo;
   |          ^ no implementation for `&Foo + &mut &mut Foo`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Add<&mut &mut Foo>` is not implemented for `&Foo`
```

So the answer is **yes**.

> If so, why does it make the compiler behave differently?

When there is a single applicable implementation of `Add<T>` (or any other generic trait), the compiler doesn't need to infer `T` from the arguments; it has already resolved `T` based on that single implementation. Basically, it's as if the trait wasn't generic at all. Therefore, the coercions that work on non-generic arguments can be applied too.